# Highlight row in ag grid on button click

Tags: ag-grid-ng2

I have a button outside the grid, on clicking of this button i am iterating the row nodes and doing a check whether the data is empty or not. If it is empty i want to highlight that row. Did not found anything which can give me any option to highlight the row in ag grid on button click.

Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for above:

In Component: may be in constructor

```
this.rowClassRules = {
  'invalid-row': (params) => {
    if (this.inValidRowNode && this.inValidRowNode.data.name === params.data.name) {
      return true;
    }
  }
};
```

On button click (in validation method), while iterating the node we need to set the data. I am setting in this way.

```
node.setDataValue('name', ' ');
```

In Html:

```
 <ag-grid-angular #agGrid rowSelection="multiple" [gridOptions]="gridOptions" [columnDefs]="gridColumnDefs" (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
     [rowClassRules]="rowClassRules">
```